# SubString of String after first hyphen, include hyphens after

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to split a string into 2 sections. The first being before the first hyphen and the second after the first hyphen but including any hyphens after. Do not include the first hyphen in either of the 2 strings.

For example, with an input string of this:

```
9077-this is a string - with a hyphen
```

`string1` should be `9077`, and `string2` should be `this is a string - with a hyphen`.

I can get `string1` by doing this:

```
Dim string1 As String = hyphenHold.Substring(0, hyphenHold.IndexOf("-")).Trim
```

But I can't figure out how to get the other side of the hyphen.

Comment: What about: hyphenHold.Substring(hyphenHold.IndexOf("-") + 1).Trim

Comment: @the_lotus Thank you, and thanks to everyone else below! Pleasantly surprised I didn't get a bunch of people telling me this is just a repeat and to use google or something! ha

Answer (score 6):

You could use [`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Split_System_Char___System_Int32_) with the overload that takes the max-count:

```
string[] bothparts = hyphenHold.Split(new[]{'-'}, 2);
string string1 = bothparts[0];
string string2 = bothparts[1];
```

If you want to use `Substring` (or `Remove` that uses `Substring`):

```
int index = hyphenHold.IndexOf('-');
string1 = hyphenHold.Remove(index); // same as hyphenHold.Substring(0, index)
string2 = hyphenHold.Substring(index+1);
```

---

VB.NET:

```
Dim bothparts = hyphenHold.Split({"-"c}, 2)
Dim string1 = bothparts(0)
Dim string2 = bothparts(1)
// ------
Dim index = hyphenHold.IndexOf("-"c)
string1 = hyphenHold.Remove(index) // same as hyphenHold.Substring(0, index)
string2 = hyphenHold.Substring(index+1)
```

Comment: User requested this on VB.NET not in C#.

Comment: @z3nth10n: oh, overlooked. Fixed

Comment: @Rango Thanks, can you explain what the 2 does after the split? Does that mean I only want it split into 2 sections? Otherwise, it would split on every hyphen?

Comment: @Dan yes exactly. Read the documentation which I have linked in my answer. It means it returns an array where the first token is the part before the hyphen and the second part is the rest(not splitted).

Comment: @Rango Thanks! This will be very helpful in the future to know. These splits have always tripped me up.

Answer (score 3):

Just do the same thing as you did but change the parameters. If you pass only one parameter, [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_) will go to the end.

```
    Dim hyphenHold As String = "9077-this is a string - with a hyphen"
    Dim string1 As String = hyphenHold.Substring(0, hyphenHold.IndexOf("-")).Trim
    Dim string2 As String = hyphenHold.Substring(hyphenHold.IndexOf("-") + 1).Trim
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll be the first that regex is overkill in this scenario.  However, it does provide some advantages.

- It is more flexible.  You could easily alter the pattern in the future to make it handle different or more complicated inputs.
- It's configurable.  You could store the pattern externally in a config setting somewhere, so you could change it without recompiling.
- It validates the input at the same time, so if the input doesn't fit the pattern, you could handle it gracefully with no extra effort.

If any of those things are important enough to you to bother with it, here's an example using regex:

```
Dim pattern As String = "^(?<before>[^-]+)-(?<after>.+)$"
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
If m.Success Then
    Dim before As String = m.Groups("before").Value
    Dim after As String = m.Groups("after").Value
End If
```